# how to remove the parameters inside the list ..and make new list android kotlin

Tags: android, list, kotlin, arraylist

I am having a json response and i want store that response of data to room table .i don't need some parameters inside data ( like slug, row_order , tax_id , etc .. ) how to remove that and make new list

```
 {
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "2637",
            "row_order": "0",
            "name": "Chennai Kichadi Ponni Rice",
            "tax_id": "1",
            "slug": "chennai-kichadi-ponni-rice-1",
            "category_id": "52",
            "subcategory_id": "196",
            "indicator": "1",
            "manufacturer": "",
            "made_in": "Chennai Kichadi Ponni Rice",
            "return_status": "1",
            "cancelable_status": "1",
            "till_status": "received",
            "image": "http://www.pasumai.co.in/upload/images/5718-2021-12-18.png",
            "status": "1",
            "popular": "0",
            "date_added": "2021-12-18 06:26:12",
            "return_max_days": "0",
            "tax": "0",
            "price": "1599",
            "tax_title": "GST",
            "tax_percentage": "0",
            "is_favorite": false,
            "is_notify_me": false,
            "variants": [
                {
                    "id": "4726",
                    "product_id": "2637",
                    "cart_count": "0",
                    "is_notify_me": false
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "2648",
            "row_order": "1",
            "name": "Double Deer Basmati Rice Gold",
            "tax_id": "9",
            "slug": "double-deer-basmati-rice-gold",
            "category_id": "52",
            "subcategory_id": "196",
            "indicator": "1",
            "manufacturer": "",
            "made_in": "Double Deer Basmati Rice Gold",
            "return_status": "1",
            "cancelable_status": "1",
            "till_status": "received",
            "image": "http://www.pasumai.co.in/upload/images/3330-2021-12-21.png",
            "status": "1",
            "popular": "0",
            "date_added": "2021-12-19 00:23:28",
            "return_max_days": "0",
            "tax": "5",
            "price": "279",
            "tax_title": "GST",
            "tax_percentage": "5",
            "is_favorite": false,
            "is_notify_me": false,
            "variants": [
                {
                    "id": "4755",
                    "product_id": "2648",
                    "cart_count": "0",
                    "is_notify_me": false
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want the new list as like this

```
        {
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "2637",
            "name": "Chennai Kichadi Ponni Rice",
            "subcategory_id": "196",
            "image": "http://www.pasumai.co.in/upload/images/5718-2021-12-18.png",
            "is_favorite": false,
        },
        {
            "id": "2648",
            "name": "Double Deer Basmati Rice Gold",
            "subcategory_id": "196",
            "image": "http://www.pasumai.co.in/upload/images/3330-2021-12-21.png",
            "is_favorite": false,
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there any method to filter ?? if yes ..please explain me with code

i want to add the new list to room table...so that i need to cut some unwanted parameters . i don't know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

You need to deserialize JSON to object, for deserialization you can use
com.google.gson add to gradle:

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.1'
}
```

create your data class

```
data class Order(
        val id:String,
        val name:String,
        val image: String,
        @SerializedName("subcategory_id")
        val subcategoryId: String,
        @SerializedName("is_favorite")
        val isFavorite: Boolean
)
```

and finally deserialize your incoming data from network

```
val responseFromNetwork = getDataFromNetwork() //here you get your json from network

val gson = Gson()
val ordersType = object : TypeToken<List<Order>>() {}.type
val itemList = gson.fromJson<List<Order>>(responseFromNetwork , ordersType)// will be deserialized only field what are in data class another one will be ignored
```

and finally add to DB your data

Comment: I understood your answer but i need what i expect..please tell me how filter the paramters  and make new list in activity or fragment like this  val products: List<Products> = response.data @Александр Волошиновский

Comment: You cant set response to list, you need to deserialize response, if you need filter you can add where condition in your query from room table

Comment: sorry , i think you don't understand my question @Александр Волошиновский